# Mostrando registros del mes actual y el mes anterior en SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Estoy trabajando un procedimiento almacenado cuyos parámetros son los siguientes:
@NIVEL -> Indica alguna línea que voy a seleccionar, y acorde la que seleccione mostrará los registros pertenecientes a esa columna. De lo contrario muestra un RAISERROR.
@MES -> Indica los registros que me mostrará del mes que vaya a enviar como parámetro. Entre 1-12.
@AÑO -> Muestra los registros en base al año que seleccione como parámetro.

En base a estos parámetros, me devuelve como salida cinco columnas que son:
LINEA -> Las líneas pertenecientes a lo que mande como parámetro en @NIVEL.
MES_ANTERIOR -> Información del mes anterior al que envío como parámetro en base a @MES y @AÑO.
MES_ACTUAL -> Información del mes actual en base a lo que envío como parámetro en @MES y @AÑO.
DIFERENCIA -> La resta de MES_ANTERIOR - MES_ACTUAL.
PORCENTAJE -> Valor que varia acorde a la línea solicitada y que muestra un valor si MES_ANTERIOR es menor a MES_ACTUAL, entiéndase también si la DIFERENCIA es valor negativo.

Habiendo explicado de lo que trata mi procedimiento, muestro el código que tengo al momento:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SP_NIVELES(
@NIVEL VARCHAR(70), 
@MES INT,
@AÑO INT
)
AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @FECHA_ANTERIOR DATE;

IF (@MES = 1)
    BEGIN
        SET @FECHA_ANTERIOR = DATEFROMPARTS(@AÑO-1, 12, 1);
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @FECHA_ANTERIOR = DATEFROMPARTS(@AÑO, @MES-1, 1);
    END

DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (
    LINEA VARCHAR(70),
    MES_ANTERIOR DECIMAL(17, 2),
    MES_ACTUAL DECIMAL(17, 2),
    DIFERENCIA DECIMAL(17, 2),
    PORCENTAJE DECIMAL(5, 2)
);

IF (@NIVEL = 'LINEAMC')
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TEMP
        SELECT LINEAMC AS LINEA,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) = DATEPART(MONTH, @FECHA_ANTERIOR) THEN MONTODEBITO ELSE 0 END -
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) = DATEPART(MONTH, @FECHA_ANTERIOR) THEN MONTOCREDITO ELSE 0 END) AS MES_ANTERIOR,
        SUM(CASE WHEN MONTH(FECHA) = @MES AND YEAR(FECHA) = @AÑO THEN MONTODEBITO ELSE 0 END - 
        CASE WHEN MONTH(FECHA) = @MES AND YEAR(FECHA) = @AÑO THEN MONTOCREDITO ELSE 0 END) AS MES_ACTUAL,
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) = DATEPART(MONTH, @FECHA_ANTERIOR) THEN MONTODEBITO ELSE 0 END -
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) = DATEPART(MONTH, @FECHA_ANTERIOR) THEN MONTOCREDITO ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) = @MES THEN MONTODEBITO ELSE 0 END -
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) = @MES THEN MONTOCREDITO ELSE 0 END) AS DIFERENCIA,
        (CASE WHEN SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) = CASE WHEN @MES = 1 THEN 12 ELSE @MES - 1 END THEN MONTODEBITO ELSE 0 END -
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) = CASE WHEN @MES = 1 THEN 12 ELSE @MES - 1 END THEN MONTOCREDITO ELSE 0 END) 
        < SUM(CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) = @MES THEN MONTODEBITO ELSE 0 END -
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(MONTH, FECHA) = @MES THEN MONTOCREDITO ELSE 0 END) THEN
        (SELECT PORCENTAJE FROM TOLERANCIA WHERE ID_TOLERANCIA = 1) ELSE 0 END) AS PORCENTAJE
        FROM PRUEBAOPEX 
        WHERE LINEAMC IS NOT NULL 
        AND YEAR(FECHA) IN (@AÑO, @AÑO-1)
        GROUP BY LINEAMC;
        SELECT * FROM @TEMP
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('El valor de @NIVEL no es válido. Debe ser LINEAMC, LINEANIVEL2, LINEANIVEL3, LINEANIVEL4 o LINEANIVEL5.', 16, 1);
    END
END
```

Son varias líneas las que consulto, pero para no extender código solo hago la muestra de una línea. El procedimiento me funciona bien, me muestra los valores de tolerancia, mes anterior, mes actual y la línea correcta.

Solo tengo un problema, y es que por ejemplo. Si hago uso de la siguiente parte de código:

```
AND YEAR(FECHA) IN (@AÑO, @AÑO-1)
```

Dentro de mi tabla solo tengo registros de enero del año 2021. El detalle está que si envío como parámetro de @AÑO 2022, me sigue mostrando esos datos cuando en realidad no me debería mostrar nada. Lo tengo así debido a que si mando como parámetros @MES = 1 y @AÑO 2021, en mes anterior me muestra la información de diciembre del año de 2020. No he encontrado otra forma de poderlo hacer.

También intente de la siguiente manera:

```
AND YEAR(FECHA) = @AÑO
```

De esta forma ya no me muestra los registros si mandará como parámetro un año diferente a 2021. Pero si mandará como parámetro de @MES = 1, en mes anterior me muestra diciembre pero del mismo año (2021) y no del 2020.

Me gustaría saber que debería de hacer para que me muestra diciembre del año anterior en caso de envía enero como parámetro pero que esos registros no se muestren en los demás años. Así como también que no muestre registros de un año diferente si mandará como parámetro de @AÑO un año en dónde no tenga registros realmente.

Agradezco la posible ayuda brindada.

Comment: Agrega el condicional de que si @MES es 1 al disminuir también disminuye el año

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes agregar una variable `@FECHA_SIGUIENTE` que sea el primer día del mes siguiente al actual y cambiar:

```
AND YEAR(FECHA) IN (@AÑO, @AÑO-1)
```

Por

```
AND FECHA >= @FECHA_ANTERIOR and FECHA <= @FECHA_SIGUIENTE
```

De esa forma se toman los registros desde el día 1 a la media noche del mes anterior hasta los del último día del mes actual a las 23:59:59

Se vería así:

```
    DECLARE @FECHA_ANTERIOR DATE;
    DECLARE @FECHA_SIGUIENTE DATE = DATEADD(MONTH , 1, DATEFROMPARTS(@AÑO, @MES, 1));

    IF (@MES = 1)
        BEGIN
            SET @FECHA_ANTERIOR = DATEFROMPARTS(@AÑO - 1, 12, 1);
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @FECHA_ANTERIOR = DATEFROMPARTS(@AÑO, @MES - 1, 1);
        END

            -- RESTO DE CÓDIGO
            -- AND YEAR(FECHA) IN (@AÑO, @AÑO-1)
              AND FECHA >= @FECHA_ANTERIOR and FECHA < @FECHA_SIGUIENTE
```